# Constructors and get and set methods togther in java

Tags: java

Hi there I have this code at the moment as a basic program which just gets a persons name, phone number and account number and then prints it out in the main method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CustomerData {
    String name;
    String phoneNumber;
    String accountCode;

    String setname() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What is customers name ?");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();

        return name;

    }

    String setNumber() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What is customers Phone Number ?");
        String phone = scanner.nextLine();

        return phone;
    }

    String setAccountCode() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What is customers account code ?");
        String account = scanner.nextLine();
        scanner.close();

        return account;
    }

    public void getInfo() {
        System.out.println("\nCustomer Name: "+this.name);
        System.out.println("Customer Phone Number: "+this.phoneNumber);
        System.out.println("Customer Account Code: "+this.accountCode);
    }

}
```

```
public class BankAccountTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        CustomerData p1 = new CustomerData();
        p1.name = p1.setname();
        p1.phoneNumber = p1.setNumber();
        p1.accountCode = p1.setAccountCode();

        p1.getInfo();

    }
}
```

However I want to use a constructor like this in my object

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CustomerData {
    String name;
    String phoneNumber;
    String accountCode;

    CustomerData(String name, String phoneNumber, String accountCode){
        this.name = name;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.accountCode = accountCode;
    }

    CustomerData(){
        this.name = "Unknown";
        this.phoneNumber = "Unknown";
        this.accountCode = "No Registered Account Code";
    }

    String setname() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What is customers name ?");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();

        return name;

    }

    String setNumber() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What is customers Phone Number ?");
        String phone = scanner.nextLine();

        return phone;
    }

    String setAccountCode() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What is customers account code ?");
        String account = scanner.nextLine();
        scanner.close();

        return account;
    }

    public void getInfo() {
        System.out.println("\nCustomer Name: "+this.name);
        System.out.println("Customer Phone Number: "+this.phoneNumber);
        System.out.println("Customer Account Code: "+this.accountCode);
    }

}
```

Is it then okay to reuse the same main method with this constructor added or will I need to change my main method.

Comment: the answer is no

Comment: by adding parametrize cunstructor and default constructor you can use both constructor to initialize an object.

Comment: Move the `Scanner's` to the `BankAccountTest#main()` method, retrieve the necessary data and then initialize `CustomerData` by calling the constructor. It's better to return `String` in the `getInfo()` method, and then print it in any convenient way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need to change your main method. You can call the parametrized constructor like -

`CustomerData p1 = new CustomerData("Mary", "9191919191", "12345");`